# How do I fix this invalid JSON that wasn't escaped? (in PHP)

Tags: php, json, escaping

My website is supposed to process data from a POST where the body of the POST document is a JSON Object. Unfortunately the body of some POSTs look like this, for example:

```
{ "FromAddress": "user@gmail.com", "Subject": "Note to self", "BodyPlain": "
this
is
a
multiline
test
what about these? \n\n
.
" }
```

Of course this isn't valid JSON, it ought to look like this:

```
{ "FromAddress": "user@gmail.com", "Subject": "Note to self", "BodyPlain": "\nthis\nis\na\nmultiline\ntest\nwhat about these? \\n\\n\n.\n" }
```

What's the simplest way to deal with this situation? I'm hoping for a solution something like this:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {
    $in = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $in = some_escape_function($in);  // is there a simple one-liner that can go here?
    $indata = json_decode($in,true);
}
```

Without fixing it, json_decode will only return NULL because the input is not valid JSON.

It needs to be able to properly escape any other troublesome inputs.

Granted, the best solution would be to escape it properly in the first place. I'm looking for an immediate workaround as well as how to advise the client for proper escaping.

Answer (score 0):

That simple one-line fixing function is [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). See it in action:

```
$bad_json = <<< END
{ "FromAddress": "user@gmail.com", "Subject": "Note to self", "BodyPlain": "
this
is
a
multiline
test
what about these? \n\n
.
" }
END
;

print_r(
    json_decode(
        str_replace("\n", "\\n", 
            trim($bad_json)
        ), TRUE
    )
);
echo("===================\n");
echo(json_last_error_msg());
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [FromAddress] => user@gmail.com
    [Subject] => Note to self
    [BodyPlain] =>
this
is
a
multiline
test
what about these?


.

)
===================
No error
```

Comment: Assuming no newlines ever occur outside of a string, of course.

Comment: I would write 
`preg_replace('~\r?\n~', "\\n", trim($bad_json))` instead of str_replace

Comment: This solution handles exactly one substitution case, I need to be sure that all problematic characters will be accounted for, which is why I was hoping for a built in solution.

Comment: There is an error! the literal \n's have been stripped out.

Comment: There is no backslash followed by `n` in the original text. The two `\n` present in the incorrect JSON are the JSON representation of a new line. Those new lines were correctly decoded and you can see them in the output.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams if there are newlines scattered through the incorrect JSON outside strings then no built-in function can save it. Writing a custom JSON parser is the only solution I can see (and it is not that difficult that it seems).

Comment: @AlexandrKapustin it doesn't help much when the newline is present outside strings, as noted by Ignacio.